# why does this onclicklistener not work?

Tags: android

I created this click listener in a android project, it is taken from a tutorial.
It worked there but does not seem to work when I tried it in my new app.

```
 ImageView animals = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anim);

    animals.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent animalsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, animals.class);

            // Start the new activity
            startActivity(animalsIntent);
        }
    });
```

The app crashes when I do this.
This is the logcat error message:

```
03-13 23:28:21.750 7734-7734/com.example.android.trollsounds E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.android.trollsounds, PID: 7734
                                                                               android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.android.trollsounds/com.example.android.trollsounds.animals}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1895)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1589)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4228)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4187)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4515)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4483)
                                                                                   at com.example.android.trollsounds.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22288)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: this code is written within the oncreate method of the mainactivity

Comment: share your full code and what error you are getting

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work"? Does the code compile? What happens when you click the button? Does the app crash? If so, what is the error? Also, show a [mcve]. In particular, show the class and method as code, not just explain it in a comment. And what is your import for `OnClickListener`?

Comment: this onclicklsitener is foe a imageview,but when i click on the imageview in my app it crashes,i have added the error in the main question

Comment: Did you even read the exception?  It tells you what the problem is

Comment: i am new to android so i cant tell what that means

Comment: have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? .... < did you look in you android manifest? you have to add the activity in there also... sounds like you didnt. you cant just add a class and go into that class...the class has to be associated with an activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
animals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent animalsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, animals.class);

        // Start the new activity
        startActivity(animalsIntent);
    }
});
```

In the onClickListerner you had (new OnClickListener(), should new new View.OnclickListener. This should work for you

Answer (score -1):

In `animals.setOnClickListiner`, you need to do  `new View.OnClickListener()`instead of  `new OnClickListener()`. Hope that helps!

```
      ImageView animals = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anim);
      //Its View.OnClickListener()
       animals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
     //Also change to this instead of GameActivity.this
            Intent animalsIntent = new Intent(this, animals.class);

        // Start the new activity
        startActivity(animalsIntent);
        }
    });
```

Also, change `Intent animalsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, animals.class);` to `Intent animalsIntent = new Intent(this, animals.class);`

**EDIT:**
You also have a ActivityNotFound error, meaning that the animals class dosent exist. Try checking the name

Comment: Show the logcat error message,It will make it way easier to answer your question. By editing your question.

Comment: how can i find the required line in the logcat?

Comment: i have added the logcat to the main question please check

Comment: Whoa you have 3 errors in your app. First, use a Button instead you a ImageView (change type in xml) then, there is activity not found meaning that the animals activity dose not exist. Try cheking the name. Third, (In my answer)

Comment: A OnClickListiner dosent work for a imageView. Consider using ImageButton to make a clickable image.

Comment: it works now i had not declared it in the androidmanifest.xml file,i thought android does it for you.Thanks for your time,really appreciate it